# Pysdm has disabled my ability to write to my storage partition

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 7 and Mint 13 Cinnamon. As well as their respective partitions, I also have a large one (NTFS) for storing all my music, videos, documents etc. I downloaded `pysdm`, as I was told it would enable me to configure Linux to auto-mount my storage partition. It has indeed been helpful in auto-mounting my storage; however, since installing it, I can no longer write to the partition, which makes 500GB of my hard drive utterly useless! I've tried to unselect the `Mount file system in read only mode` option, but the program keeps re-checking it after I close that window (and even when I click apply).

**Why is it doing this** and **how can I get it to recognize that I need to read *AND* write on that partition**?

Comment: This [question](http://superuser.com/questions/260273/problem-after-auto-mount-ntfs-drives-using-pysdm/260318#260318) is similar to what you've described.

That user strayed from historical convention with the fstab partition mount point. Edit your post, include your */etc/fstab* file contents. Hint: It is a simple matter to add the [uid/gid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab#fat) options to an existing windows partion mount definition.